# Error jquery conflict in wordpress admin with plugin and theme

Tags: wordpress, composer-php

I use plugin Visual composer and create theme default ice underscores.me but it conflict jquery in wordpress admin. I add widget and don't save data. I deactive theme or plugin visual composer it no conflict. Help me

[image: screenshot]

Comment: it seems like one of you plugin is doing this issue that plugin is related to editor.  disable your plugins and check which plugin is occurring this issue than we can do something while modify that specific line

Comment: it don't error as i deactive plugin visual composer. in file functions.php, i write                          
 add_action('vc_before_init','vinmart_vc_before_init');
}

function vinmart_vc_before_init(){
  require_once(get_template_directory().'/vc-composer/block-info.php');}

Comment: i fixed it. i used if(!is_admin()){   add_action('vc_before_init','vinmart_vc_before_init'); }  }